# Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-fuctions'

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wanna deploy Firebase Function, but when I pass command firebase deploy, its show this error

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-fuctions'
>   Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before
>   deploying.

I installed npm install package, but won't work for me. I changed dependencies in package.json, but won't work for me. Please help me

Node version v8.9.3

npm version v5.5.1

firebase version  3.17.6

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.11.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Does node_modules directory contain firebase-functions?

Comment: yes its fuctions contains node module folder

Comment: I meant, in your **functions directory** does the `node_modules` directory contain the `firebase-functions` directory? Also, check this and make sure you are executing commands in the correct directory - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set_up_and_initialize

Comment: C:\Users\Skipper\Desktop\node\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions its exist

Comment: thanks its solved by installing      npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save  in functions Folder.. thanks Bro]

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @kunalgharate It might be worth if you post your solution as an answer. That way others can more easily find your solution if they find this question.

Comment: yes,  there is not a questions related this topic and also its help newbie who don't have idea about it .